# Is there a way to change Rows Per Page in a v-data-table (vuetify) without the table resetting to page 1

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify data table where I would like to keep the current page it is on when I change the rows per page number. It doesn't seem to trigger the pagination sync whenever I change rows per page. (The pagination sync should handle keeping track of which page as it works for other filters on the page e.g. when sorting the records, it will stay on the current page). Is this just how v-data-table works when changing rows per page?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "same page." If there are 100 total rows in your table, and you are displaying 10 rows per page, and you are currently viewing rows 31-40 (i.e. "page 3"), and you switch to 50 rows per page, what page should you be on? With the new rows-per-page, there will only be 2 total pages, so being on "page 3" would be meaningless. If you switched to 5 rows per page, then items 31-35 would be on page 7 and items 36-40 would be on page 8. Which page should be displayed?

Since there is no clear, unambiguous definition of "same page," Vuetify defaults to returning to the first page as a sensible behavior.

However, for sake of argument, let's decide that by "same page" you mean that whatever item was on the first row of the table before you changed the items per page will remain visible on the screen after the items per page change. Obviously, if the number of items per page is decreased, e.g. goes from 10 to 5, you can't display ALL of the items that were on screen before the change.

Here's [a demo of this in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/NWGdVrp).

`v-data-table` has a `@pagination` event that fires every time the page changes, both when clicking through the pages, and when the number of items per page changes. The event handler receives an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  "page": 5,         // 1-based index, i.e. first page is 1 (not zero)
  "itemsPerPage": 5, // current items per page
  "pageStart": 20,   // 0-based index of the first item displayed on the screen
  "pageStop": 25,    // 0-based index of the first item on the *next* page
  "pageCount": 20,   // total number of pages
  "itemsLength": 100 // total number of rows
}
```

We can store these values for later use, including updating the current page when the number of items per page changes.

First, you'll need to add two props to your `v-data-table`:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="5"
  :page.sync="pagination.page"
  @pagination="updatePage"
></v-data-table>
```

`page.sync` allows you to programmatically set the current page, i.e. keep it in sync with a specified data prop. `@pagination` allows you to specify a function to receive and handle the pagination info whenever it changes. The script section of your component would look like this:

```js
export default {
  name: 'MyComponentWithADataTable',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [ /* ...data table header info... */ ],
      items: [ /* ...the actual data in the table... */ ],
      pagination: {}, // <-- holds our pagination data
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstItem () {
      // the index of the item that is the top row displayed on the screen
      return this.pagination.pageStart
    },
    itemsPerPage () {
      // the current number of items per page
      return this.pagination.itemsPerPage
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updatePage (pagination) {
      // detect change in itemsPerPage
      if (this.itemsPerPage !== pagination.itemsPerPage) {
        for (let p = 0; p < pagination.pageCount; p++) {
          // figure out the page bounds
          const start = p * pagination.itemsPerPage
          const end = start + pagination.itemsPerPage
          // is the target item on this page?
          if (this.firstItem >= start && this.firstItem < end) {
            // yes, so set the page to this page
            pagination.page = p + 1
            // break out of the loop
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      // update the pagination info
      this.pagination = pagination
    }
  },
}
```